# Why does "tlmgr info --list --only-installed" not list some of the installed packages?

Tags: packages, tlmgr

Why does the command

`tlmgr info --list --only-installed`

not list some of the installed packages (e.g. graphicx, MnSymbol etc.)?

I need a list of "all" the available packages on my machine with a short description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It lists `tlmgr` packages not latex packages. `graphicx` is part of `latex-graphics` on ctan and for `tlmgr` just as `longtable` and `array` are part of `latex-tools`

The entry for `graphics` does list the contained latex packages

```
$ tlmgr list graphics
package:     graphics
category:    Package
shortdesc:   The LaTeX standard graphics bundle
longdesc:    This is a collection of LaTeX packages for: producing colour including graphics (eg PostScript) files rotation and scaling of text in LaTeX documents.
```

**`It comprises the packages color, graphics, graphicx, trig, epsfig, keyval, and lscape.`**

```
installed:   Yes
revision:    61315
sizes:       src: 261k, doc: 2637k, run: 141k
relocatable: No
cat-license: lppl1.3c
cat-topics:  graphics collection
cat-contact-bugs: https://www.latex-project.org/bugs/
cat-contact-home: https://www.latex-project.org/
collection:  collection-latex
```