# List all packages, with short description, installed with Texlive

Tags: packages

I need to build a plain text file with a list of all `LaTeX` packages with a short description, e.g.

```
a0poster: Support for designing posters on large paper.
a2ac: AFM to AFM plus Composites.
a2ping: Advanced PS, PDF, EPS converter.
.
.
.
```

I [learned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645115/33634) that the command  `tlmgr info --list --only-installed` lists `tlmgr` packages, not `LaTeX` packages installed on my machine. How do Ilist "all" packages installed with Texlive on my Linux machine, with a short description the way `tlmgr` command does?

Alternatively, where can I find a full list of all packages like on the [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/:A) website?

I don't care about false positives. My purpose is to obtain something like in the screenshot:

[image]

It shows the package description when the package name is moused over.

Comment: This might be a bit nit-picky, but in general it might not be quite clear what constitutes a "LaTeX package". One interpretation would be: Anything you can load with `\usepackage`, but then already `a2ping` is not a package. Then again `biblatex` actually consists of several `.sty` files, but you are only supposed to do `\usepackage{biblatex}`, the other `.sty`s are not intended to be used in `\usepackage` in documents, even though you could try that (you'd get an error most likely, but LaTeX would try to load the "package").

Comment: Maybe you can have something similar to what you want if you get the `tlmgr` list and remove all the packages that do not have a `.sty` in the `...tex/latex` hierarchy. But still you'll have false positive/negative, depending on your definition of "package"

Comment: I edite my question showing my purpose.

Comment: Maybe the better title of your question is "list of all tlmgr packages" no "LaTeX packages". In your description, we can read that you want to list all tlmgr packages and then use a subset of this list for your mouse-over application.

Comment: @wipet with `tlmgr` I cannot list packages like graphicx, MnSymbol etc. Look at my previous question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645102/33634

Comment: the ctan catalogue is basically what you are asking for  use the URL https://www.ctan.org/pkg/packagename

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't want to search for the single package. I need a list of all the packages like in https://www.ctan.org/pkg/:A, but for all the packages (not alphabetically separated). I thought that this list existed somewhere.

Comment: it does exist in the ctan backend but not available for bulk download by design